# Can't create external initiators from chainlink CLI

Tags: chainlink

We're trying to set external initiators to our chainlink containers deployed in GKE cluster according to the docs: https://docs.chain.link/docs/external-initiators-in-nodes/

I log into the the pod:

`kubectl exec -it -n chainlink chainlink-75dd5b6bdf-b4kwr -- /bin/bash`

And there I attempt to create external initiators:

```
root@chainlink-75dd5b6bdf-b4kwr:/home/root# chainlink initiators create xxx xxx
No help topic for 'initiators'
```

I don’t even see initiators in chainlink cli options:

```
root@chainlink-75dd5b6bdf-b4kwr:/home/root# chainlink
NAME:
   chainlink - CLI for Chainlink

USAGE:
   chainlink [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]

VERSION:
   0.9.10@7cd042c1a94c57219ed826a6eab46752d63fa67a

COMMANDS:
   admin           Commands for remotely taking admin related actions
   attempts, txas  Commands for managing Ethereum Transaction Attempts
   bridges         Commands for Bridges communicating with External Adapters
   config          Commands for the node's configuration
   job_specs       Commands for managing Job Specs (jobs V1)
   jobs            Commands for managing Jobs (V2)
   keys            Commands for managing various types of keys used by the Chainlink node
   node, local     Commands for admin actions that must be run locally
   runs            Commands for managing Runs
   txs             Commands for handling Ethereum transactions
   help, h         Shows a list of commands or help for one command

GLOBAL OPTIONS:
   --json, -j     json output as opposed to table
   --help, -h     show help
   --version, -v  print the version
```

Chainlink version 0.9.10.

Could you please clarify what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tested on `smartcontract/chainlink:0.10.14` image. Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the `FEATURE_EXTERNAL_INITIATORS` environment variable set to true in your .env file as such:

`FEATURE_EXTERNAL_INITIATORS=true`

This will open up access to the `initiators` command in the Chainlink CLI and you can resume the instructions from there.